# Ensuring Promised Equity is well secured when joining a start up

Tags: contract-law, business, ownership, shareholders

I am currently working for a start up and we have been talking about an equity deal, where I would be compensated with some percentage of the company plus salary.

I want to ensure everything is done correctly and I am actually able to secure the equity I am promised. I am willing to hire a lawyer if needed, but don't want to be thousands on lawyer expenses without knowing a little bit about what needs to be done.

Right now, everything is up for discussion, nothing is off limits and basically what I am looking for is a percentage, say 10% + salary. Once we agree on this figure, how does one ensure the promised equity is actually secured?

In the event, the company declares bankruptcy, the CEO decides to sell, transfer or step down, how would I be able to ensure that I am given whatever I was promised. Lastly, assuming I currently own 10% of the company, how and when can I actually 'claim' the equity and convert it to cash, if needed?

Comment: Ask for a copy of the articles of incorporation.  This should directly address the specifics of the last two questions.